# ListView no longer display inside Tab

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost, android-support-library

I haven't touched this codebase in a couple of months.  Now that I've picked it up again, some code that I didn't think I'd changed has stopped working: All listfragment listviews in the app populated by a simplecursoradapter have stopped working and are just blank.  At first I thought the cursor or the database was at fault or that perhaps the adapter wasn't being set correctly, so I added some debugging to the onLoadFinished:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Log.d("IndexListFragment", "Rows returned: " + cursor.getCount());
    Log.d("IndexListFragment", cursor.getColumnName(0));
    Log.d("IndexListFragment", mAdapter.toString());
    Log.d("IndexListFragment", this.getListView().getAdapter().toString());

    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

This returns what I'd expect:

```
IndexListFragment: Rows returned: 2324
IndexListFragment: _id
IndexListFragment: android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter@41d06a18
IndexListFragment: android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter@41d06a18
```

So as far as I can tell, the cursor is there and full of data, but swapping it in doesn't get the listview populated.  Any ideas?

For completeness, here's the onCreate where the adapter is created and set:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] from = new String[] { GuidebookProvider.COL_NAME,
            GuidebookProvider.COL_GRADE };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

And the onCreateLoader:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle loaderArgs) {
    String orderBy = GuidebookProvider.COL_NAME;
    String[] projection = new String[] { GuidebookProvider.COL_ID, GuidebookProvider.COL_NAME, GuidebookProvider.COL_GRADE };


    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            GuidebookProvider.CONTENT_URI_CLIMB, projection, null, null,
            orderBy);
}
```

Edit: I've done a little more work debugging this issue.  The fragment works fine if I run it directly from an activity like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame.setId(android.R.id.content);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(IndexListFragment.ARGUMENT_INDEX_TYPE, IndexListFragment.IndexType.ALPHA.value);

            Fragment indexListFragment = new IndexListFragment();
            indexListFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, indexListFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

However, calling it as part of a Tab ends up with a blank tab:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tab_host);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(IndexListFragment.ARGUMENT_INDEX_TYPE,
                IndexListFragment.IndexType.ALPHA.value);
        Drawable drawable = null;
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("A-Z")
                .setIndicator("A-Z", drawable), IndexListFragment.class, args);

    }
}
```

Here's my xml for the tabhost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The fact that the fragment populates correctly when called directly but not when called from within a tab seems to show that the problem isn't at all with the cursors or adapters but with the way the listfragment operating inside a tab.

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong (or what's changed in the last couple of updates of the SDK) to break this code?  It used to work fine.

Comment: why is the third param null in constructor of `SimpleCursorAdapter`?. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Comment: The loader populates the cursor in a different thread so you don't hang up the main application thread waiting for the database to populate the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This Code may help you just try it

### ViewAllLesson.java :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.xyz.R;
import com.xyz.db.LessonDatabaseConnector;
import com.xyz.pojo.AssignmentPojo;
import com.xyz.pojo.LessonPojo;

public class ViewAllLessons extends Fragment {
    public LessonDatabaseConnector dao;
    private View rootView;
    List<LessonPojo> lessons;
    ArrayList<String> con = new ArrayList<String>();
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    LessonCustomAdapter lessonCustomAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    public static CheckBox selectAll;
    private Button deleteBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.add_exams);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_view_all_list, container,
                false);

        // dao = new AssignmentDatabaseConnector(getActivity());

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Lesson_ListAll);
        selectAll = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.SelectAll);
        deleteBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LessonDeleteBtn);
        Button addNew = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LessonAddNewBtn);
        addNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Lesson lesson = new Lesson();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, lesson).commit();
            }
        });

        // viewgr.setScrollContainer(false);
        dao = new LessonDatabaseConnector(getActivity());
        lessons = dao.getAllLessonList();
        lessonCustomAdapter = new LessonCustomAdapter(getActivity(), lessons,
                this);
        listView.setAdapter(lessonCustomAdapter);

        /* To Check List View is empty */
        if (lessons.size() <= 0) {

            View empty = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty);

            ListView list = (ListView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Lesson_ListAll);
            list.setEmptyView(empty);
            listView.setVisibility(0);
            empty.setVisibility(1);

        }

        selectAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    LessonCustomAdapter.flag = true;
                    lessonCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    LessonCustomAdapter.flag = false;
                    LessonCustomAdapter.checkedvalue.clear();
                    lessonCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        // Set the list adapter and get TODOs list via DAO

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LessonDatabaseConnector dao = new LessonDatabaseConnector(
                        getActivity());

                for (int i = 0; i < LessonCustomAdapter.checkedvalue.size(); i++) {
                    //
                    System.out
                            .println("===========LessonCustomAdapter.checkedvalue.size()==========SIZE======>>>>"
                                    + LessonCustomAdapter.checkedvalue.size());
                    System.out
                            .println("===========DELETED LESSON=================>>>>"
                                    + LessonCustomAdapter.checkedvalue.get(i));
                    dao.DeleteLesson(LessonCustomAdapter.checkedvalue.get(i));
                }
                LessonCustomAdapter.flag = false;

                ViewAllLessons viewAllLessons = new ViewAllLessons();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, viewAllLessons)
                        .commit();
                // finish();

            }

        });

        return rootView;

    }

    private List<AssignmentPojo> getAllAssignmentsList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

### LessonCustomAdapter :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.xyz.R;
import com.xyz.pojo.LessonPojo;

public class LessonCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    protected static boolean flag = false;
    private TextView mLessonTitle, mLessonDate;
    private final Context context;
    List<LessonPojo> Lessons;
    private ViewAllLessons viewAllLessons;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private CheckBox SingleChk;
    public static ArrayList<Long> checkedvalue = new ArrayList<Long>();

    LessonCustomAdapter(Context context, List<LessonPojo> Lessons2,
            ViewAllLessons viewAllLessons) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Lessons = Lessons2;
        this.viewAllLessons = viewAllLessons;
        for (int i = 0; i < Lessons2.size(); i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Lessons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_view_row_list, parent,
                    false);
        }

        mLessonDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.LessonDate);
        mLessonDate.setText(Lessons.get(position).getLdate());

        mLessonTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.LessonTitle);
        mLessonTitle.setText(Lessons.get(position).getLtitle());

        SingleChk = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.singleChk);

        /*
         * if (flag) { System.out.println("66666666666666666666666666666666" +
         * flag); for (int i = 0; i < Lessons.size(); i++) {
         * SingleChk.setChecked(flag); SingleChk.setEnabled(!flag); }
         * 
         * } else { SingleChk.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position)); }
         */
        checkedvalue.clear();
        if (ViewAllLessons.selectAll.isChecked()) {
            SingleChk.setChecked(true);
            Boolean val = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < Lessons.size(); i++) {

                checkedvalue.add(Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(i).getId()));
                System.out
                        .println("ADD SUCCEFULLYYYYYYYY  ======================  "
                                + Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(position).getId()));

            }

        } else {
            SingleChk.setChecked(false);
            checkedvalue.clear();
        }

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                ViewSingleLesson viewSingleLesson = new ViewSingleLesson();

                bundle.putString("ID", Lessons.get(position).getId());
                bundle.putString("TITLE", Lessons.get(position).getLtitle());
                bundle.putString("COURSE", Lessons.get(position).getLcourse());
                bundle.putString("LEVEL", Lessons.get(position).getLlevel());
                bundle.putString("CLASS", Lessons.get(position).getLclass());
                bundle.putString("DATE", Lessons.get(position).getLdate());
                bundle.putString("DESC", Lessons.get(position).getLdesc());
                bundle.putString("ATTACH", Lessons.get(position).getLfilepath());

                viewSingleLesson.setArguments(bundle);
                viewAllLessons.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, viewSingleLesson)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        SingleChk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Boolean val = false;
                Toast.makeText(context, "hi " + Lessons.get(position).getId(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedvalue.size(); i++) {
                        if (checkedvalue.get(i) == Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(
                                position).getId())) {
                            val = true;
                            System.out
                                    .println("DUPLICATE  ======================  "
                                            + Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(
                                                    position).getId()));
                        } else {
                            val = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (val == false) {
                        checkedvalue.add(Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(position)
                                .getId()));
                        System.out
                                .println("ADD SUCCEFULLYYYYYYYY  ======================  "
                                        + Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(position)
                                                .getId()));
                    }
                } else {
                    ViewAllLessons.selectAll.setChecked(false);
                    checkedvalue.remove(Long.parseLong(Lessons.get(position)
                            .getId()));
                    System.out
                            .println("Removed SUCCEFULLYYYYYYYY  ======================  "
                                    + Integer.parseInt(Lessons.get(position)
                                            .getId()));
                    // itemChecked.set(position, false);
                }

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my question at all.

I've updated my question to further explain my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got a chance to have a look at this today and finally sorted it out.  The problem was in my xml layout setup.  Oddly, according to my git repository, this file hasn't changed for 9 months so I guess I was doing something that only worked by accident.  I found a tutorial FragmentTabHosts with a different layout and updated my layout to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That somehow fixed the issue.  A bit more hunting around revealed an example layout xml for FragmentTabHost in the TabActivity documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

I updated to use the version found in the documentation and it also works:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Given I found it in Android's documentation, I'll stick with this version.